# What is the origin of the Danish dough whisk?

Tags: denmark, cooking

Recently I've been trying to find more information on the [Danish dough whisk](https://utensil.org/dough-whisk/), which is a tool used for mixing thicker dough by hand. [Every](https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/this-danish-dough-whisk-can-make-any-bread-cake-or-muffin-better-article) [article](https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/what-is-a-danish-dough-whisk/) I [read](https://www.seriouseats.com/danish-dough-whisk-brodpisker) about it seems to have a variation of the same spiel--that it was made in Denmark, that Danish people call it a "bread whipper" or "brødpisker" or "brodpisker", that it's often manufactured in Poland--but I can't find any texts in either Danish or English to corroborate any part of that, including the names. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a _history_ question?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what else to call it--It's a cooking implement, but this question is not strictly related to cooking; I'm asking how/where/when the dough whisk was developed, or at least how potential misinformation about it was codified. I considered that it might be odd in the same way that questions about, e.g., the origin of a stapler might be odd here, but I could not find a dedicated community for asking about the history of cooking. I'm sorry if I posted in the wrong place after all!

Comment: Maybe tweak the main body of the question a little to put more emphasis on origin for this specific type of whisk, (e.g. earliest mention of use, earliest picture).

Comment: @Seanachai For what its worth, the [article on whisks](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piskeris) in the Danish Wikipedia does not mention this kind of whisk. The most common type of whisk is apparently called "balloon whisk" (*ballonpiskeris*), The article also mentions "French whisk" (*fransk piskeris*), "flat whisk" (*fladt piskeris*), and "sauce whisk" (*sovsepiskeris*). Using Google to search for sample images of *fladt piskeris*, I don't find any that match the image linked in the question.

Comment: @Seanachai I am unable to find any reference to a (Danish) dough whisk that can be unambiguously dated to pre-Y2K. I searched in English, German ("Teigbesen"), and Danish. This question seems off-topic for History Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dane here, I got curious about the same thing and have spent half an hour researching it. This is what I found out:

In Denmark the "Danish dough whisk" is more commonly called a farsrører. It was made to mix minced meat for meatballs and the like.

I have found an [add](https://arkiv.dk/vis/3097065) dated 1930-1950 that mentions a farsrører. Modern cookware websites advertises them "like the one your grandma used". The farsrører was also a part of an [exhibition at Koldinghus](https://designetc.dk/designikoner-din-hverdag/) in 2017 as an example of everyday design.

It is well known that people today use them for bread instead of minced meat, some shops sell them as a dej/farsrører (dej means dough).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much! The English sources were mostly cooking articles and didn't detail anything about the history of the utensil, so this is extremely helpful. It's interesting to see that it was originally used for meatballs; I suppose it makes sense that they'd start experimenting with other dough products afterward. 
Welcome to the History Stack Exchange! I'm grateful for your help.